# Responsiveness in Navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've got this navbar that looks something like this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg border-bottom bg-white">

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-between" id="myNav">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cdm_nav" aria-controls="myNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <form class="form-inline"> 
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend dropdown">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span>All</span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="dropdown-item">Category 1</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">Category 1</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">Category 1</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <ul id="suggestions" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="dropdown-item">Keyword...</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>

          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill nav-right">
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

https://codepen.io/arc-ranges/pen/RYqQrG

Now, this is currently how it's supposed to be for large screens. However, on smaller screens, like 1280 px, it should have:

- the nav-brand on the left side (float)
- four links and search bar on a new row (bottom)
- two links on the right side (float)

Question: What is the best way to achieve this?

I am thinking of using bootstrap grid system or hiding the entire nav and showing a different navbar using media queries.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg border-bottom bg-white">

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-between" id="myNav">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cdm_nav" aria-controls="myNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <form class="form-inline"> 
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend dropdown">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span>All</span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="dropdown-item">Category 1</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">Category 1</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">Category 1</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="dropdown">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <ul id="suggestions" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="dropdown-item">Keyword...</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill nav-right">
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Image attached for 1280px screen.[image: target design]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg border-bottom bg-white">

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex flex-wrap" id="myNav">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-left order-0 col-6 col-xl-2">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cdm_nav" aria-controls="myNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between order-2 order-xl-1 flex-nowrap col-12 col-xl-8">
    <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex flex-row justify-content-around justify-content-xl-center col-4 offset-2 offset-xl-0 col-xl-6">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <form class="form-inline col-5 col-xl-6 justify-content-xl-center"> 
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend dropdown">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span>All</span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="dropdown-item">Category 1</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">Category 1</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">Category 1</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <ul id="suggestions" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="dropdown-item">Keyword...</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>

          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill nav-right order-1 order-xl-2 col-6 col-xl-2 d-flex justify-content-end">
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

You will probably want to play around with adding classes for the smaller view ports and any other ways you want to groom the look you're going for, you can find them here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/ , but basically this is the general idea. It shouldn't be necessary to have two different versions for different view ports and doing it that way is generally frowned upon. In my version you can accomplish it with just the Bootstrap classes and no extra CSS